# Highcharts: como fazer o gráfico aparecer mesmo sem dados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Integrei o gráfico do Highcharts com uma árvore. Então, ao selecionar uma hierarquia na árvore, automaticamente o gráfico é carregado com as informações selecionadas. Mas quando não há nada selecionado na árvore, o gráfico desaparece.

Gostaria de saber como se faz para aparecer o gráfico, mesmo quando não há dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme [documentação](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.showAxes) você pode fazer isso setando a propriedade `showAxes` para `true`.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            showAxes: true
        }
});
```

Comment: @lago Correia Guimarães Certo! Funcionou parcialmente. Ele não está mostrando o eixo x, somente o Y.

Comment: Entendo. Creio não ser possível, mas paralelamente lhe trago outra possível solução: o uso do noData (alertar ao usuário que não há dados para exibir). está na documentação também. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData

Comment: exemplo de uso: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie/

Comment: Entendi. A primeira solução atende melhor minha necessidade. Obrigada